# Resolving hostname behind a proxy in Python

Tags: python, sockets, proxy, python-sockets

I am learning python sockets. However as I am behind a proxy, I am unable to resolve IP from hostnames from addresses which are not on my local network (like the internet websites). How do I do this ? 
Here is my code:

```
import socket   #for sockets
import sys  #for exit

try:
    #create an AF_INET, STREAM socket (TCP)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error, msg:
    print 'Failed to create socket. Error code: ' + str(msg[0]) + ' , Error message : ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit();

print 'Socket Created'

host = 'www.google.com'
port = 80

try:
    remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname( host )

except socket.gaierror:
    #could not resolve
    print 'Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting'
    sys.exit()

print 'Ip address of ' + host + ' is ' + remote_ip

#Connect to remote server
s.connect((remote_ip , port))

print 'Socket Connected to ' + host + ' on ip ' + remote_ip
```

Comment: Assuming you are on a linux machine, Can you make sure nslookup (hostname) fails from your command line shell?

Comment: You should probably skip resolving the hostname, and just directly connect to the proxy instead and issue a HTTP 1.0 query.

Comment: @fayyazkl: This is what I get

nslookup www.google.com
Server:  127.0.0.1
Address: 127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find www.google.com: REFUSED

Comment: @Rajesh: could you please elaborate.

Comment: @Rajesh: Trying this http://codepad.org/mkHoFyKj generates http://codepad.org/Pdeu2SJW

Comment: @humanitarian0098 that's interesting so you are running a local DNS server. Are you sure you are using the same DNS otherwise for accessing internet? I have doubts and you might have an assigned ip on may be your private local LAN as a DNS server. Please confirm

Comment: @humanitarian0098 message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.somedomain.com\r\n\r\n"

Comment: @Rajesh: adding the host parameter did not help either. A similar invalid request HTML formatted message is returned by the server.

Comment: @fayyazkl: Well probably not, I haven't configured the DNS settings, but as you've said nslookup seems to return localhost as the DNS (which is a surprise to me too). On checking my DNS from the Linux Mint Mate GUI, its shown as 14.139.5.5 (which is probably correct as I am located in India).

Comment: @humanitarian0098 hmm, may be the proxy doesn't understand HTTP 1.1. Try HTTP 1.0 format: message = "GET [http://www.somedomain.com/](http://www.somedomain.com/) HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"

Comment: @humanitarian0098 check your etc/resolv.conf. The first nameserver entry should be of 14.139.5.5. You can edit that too. Do that and try again.

Comment: @Rajesh: Its returning an HTTP 400 error. Here is the errorlog http://codepad.org/v0BXbNEg

Comment: @humanitarian0098 using my last edit on the comment? SO foobar'd the url first time I posted. GET line should contain full protocol://host/path

Comment: @fayyazkl: Looking at my system configuration, I just found out that I have resolveconf installed. So there is no reslov.conf at /etc/ . Any help on how to change this using resolveconf ?

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/resolvconf.8.html

Comment: Never mind I found one http://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf

Comment: @Rajesh: Thanks a lot. After the correction. It worked like a charm.

Comment: @humanitarian0098 so you work at National Informatics Centre, Ministry Of Comm & IT A-Block huh :) A lot can be pulled out from your IP ;)

Comment: @Rajesh: Nope, I'm from IIT Madras. The Government just gives us the connection :)

Comment: @fayyazkl: Thanks to you too. After adding manual DNS conifg, I can resolve the hostname to IP address. :)

Comment: @humanitarian0098 ahh, no wonder people flock to the IITM LUG mailing list with hproxy woes ;)

Comment: @humanitarian0098 no problem any time. It is worth noting that for e.g. Ubuntu 12.0.4 comes with a local DNS server configured by default. One has to disable that to use an external DNS. Though i am writing this on Linux mint and i don't have one by default.